# Fade In/Fade Out Through Unknown Amount of Divs, With Delay Between

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've search around and tried my best, but could not find out how to achieve the following:

1. Loop through an unknown amount of divs
2. Have some sort of animation (maybe just a simple width growth of 110%)
3. Each Div fades in/fades out
4. Delay in between the final div fading out and the first div fading in again

My Current code is as follows

[JS Fiddle Link - Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3ujb7k4L/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="popup">Popup 1</div>
    <div class="popup r">Popup 2</div>
    <div class="popup b">Popup 3</div>
    <div class="popup g">Popup 4</div>
    <div class="popup y">Popup 5</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.popup {
    display: none;
    width: 400px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
.r{background:red}
.b{background:blue}
.g{background:green}
.y{background:yellow}
```

jQuery

```
var popups = $('.popup');
var i = 0;

function step() {
    if (i >= popups.length)
        i = 0;
    $(popups[i]).fadeToggle(300);
    i++;
}

setInterval(step, 2000);
```

As you can see, my divs don't fade out until all are shown, this is not desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain together animations with a `delay` between:

```
function next() {
    if (i >= popups.length)
        i = 0;
    popups.eq(i).fadeIn(300).delay(2500).fadeOut(300).delay(1000).queue(function(){
            next();
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    i++;
}

next()
```

(note: I have used `popups.eq(i)` which is the same as `$(popups[i])`)

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3ujb7k4L/7/

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is just what I was looking for.  Out of curiosity, how would I add a longer delay at the end of the cycle?

Comment: the second `delay` (set as 1000 in this example) is the delay after fadeOut but before fadeIn of the next item.

Comment: I'm asking how to insert another delay after the 5th div fades out and before the 1st one fades back in.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var popups = $('.popup');
var i = 0;

function fadeOutLater(popup) {
    setInterval(function() {
        popup.fadeOut(500);
    }, 5000);
}

function step() {
    var popup;
    if (i >= popups.length)
        i = 0;
    popup = $(popups[i]);
    popup.fadeIn(300, fadeOutLater(popup));
    i++;
}

setInterval(step, 2000);
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear with my post, let me give a better example.  Basically one fades in stays for a little, one fades out, short delay, two fades in stays for a little, two fades out, short delay... after the last div fades out, in my code example five, there is a longer delay. Edit: with yours I get multiple up a same time.

Comment: change the numbers a bit then

Answer (score 0):

To create a longer pause between hiding the last element and showing the first element again you could skip one fadeIn/fadeOut cycle on resetting the counter:

```
var popups = $('.popup');
var i = 0;

function step() {
   if (i >= popups.length) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        $(popups[i]).delay(300).fadeIn(300).delay(200).fadeOut(300).delay(200);
        i++;
    }    
}

setInterval(step, 2000);
```

Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/r72qpher/

Comment: Ive tried a few  things but I wasn't able to define a custom value while having it work correctly.